# Can't import mysql data into elastic search

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, jdbc, logstash, logstash-jdbc

I'm trying to follow along with a course example haven't recieved any help in the FAQ's, tried everything I could find on google and here.

I'm not using docker just running this demo on my local machine(Ubunutu 18.04), both elastic search and mysql are running.

When I run "sudo bin/logstash -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/mysql.conf --path.settings /etc/logstash" 
I get the following Error: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver not loaded. Are you sure you've included the correct jdbc driver in :jdbc_driver_library?
The driver does exist and path is correct.

when I use sudo bin/logstash --config.test_and_exit -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/mysql.conf
It returns with configuration ok.

I'm using mysql-connector-java-5.1.47
openjdk version "1.8.0_181"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-8u181-b13-0ubuntu0.18.04.1-b13)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.181-b13, mixed mode)

Elasticsearch-6.4.2
Logstash-6.4.2

My mysql.conf is

```
input {
    jdbc {
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/movielens"
        jdbc_user => "grunt"
        jdbc_password => "password"
        jdbc_driver_library => "/home/alarik/mysql-connecter-java-5.1.47/mysql-connector-java-5.1.47-bin.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        statement => "SELECT * FROM movies"
    }
}

output {
    stdout { codec => json_lines }
    elasticsearch {
        "hosts" => "localhost:9200"
        "index" => "movielens-sql"
        "document_type" => "data"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem:

First check your java version:

```
root@xxxxxx:/# java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_181"
```

If you are using 1.8 then you should use the JDBC42 version.

If you are using 1.7 then you should use the JDBC41 version.

If you are using 1.6 then you should use the JDBC43 version.

mysql setup:

mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar

```
jdbc_driver_library => "//path_to_jar/mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar"
jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
```